# How to kill process similar to kill buffer

Tags: shell, comint, kill-buffer

Whenever I run into infinite loops in a script and it produces a lot of output, `C-c C-c` (`comint-interrupt-subjob`) does not reach the process and cannot be killed; being over SSH hangs communication as well.

In such scenario, I `kill-buffer` and now I have to reopen another `M-x shell`.

Is it possible to kill process no matter what and reopen buffer in the same location? For example, if shell is responsive I can do `C-d` to kill process and `M-x revert-buffer` and I reopen shell exactly as it was before closing it.

Comment: What's your platform? Does `kill -9` with the PID do what you want?

Comment: If I open two shells to the same host, and one of shells is spitting tons of output that I cannot send comint interrupt, *then* I cannot send any commands from another shell as well.

Comment: I guess what I am looking for is resetting connection in the same buffer

Comment: Put all relevant info in the question itself, please. Comments can be deleted at any time.